# Closest Value find with excel formula not working in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First question ever asked on stackoverflow for me!

I am trying to get the closes value from the columns Dim B and Dim C to the closest value of Dim A

it works fine if I do a test outside of table but when inside the table it does not work.

```
{=INDEX(Table1[@[Dim B]:[Dim C]],MATCH(MIN(ABS(Table1[@[Dim B]:[Dim C]]-[@[Dim A]])),ABS(Table1[@[Dim B]:[Dim C]]-[@[Dim A]]),0))}
```

[image: Please see image attached]

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqASn.png)

[Whats even more weird is that it works on this simple table that I just created not on the original one?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ekdr.png)

Thank you guys for your help in advance!

Regards,

Jonas Blazinskas

Comment: please write your current formula as code, not image.

Comment: Sorry fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most number functions like `MIN(range)` return `#VALUE!` when at least 1 cell in the range is `#VALUE!` (similar for `#N/A` and other errors). Those functions also usually ignore strings.

So, if you can, modify the formulas in columns `Dim A`, `Dim B` and `Dim C` so that they don't contain errors, e.g. if the original formula was `=originalFunction()`, then use following to convert errors to an empty string:

```
=IFERROR(originalFunction(), "")
```

If you cannot, then add 3 new helper columns using the `IFERROR` function and compute the closest value calculation from the new columns.

Comment: I dont think #VALUE! was the issue? See the new image that I have uploaded above please.

Comment: ah, there is a `#VALUE` in the evaluation step when calculating a subtraction - looks like you will have to use a number like `0` or `9999` instead of empty string `""`... or you can wrap all parts of the formula that can produce additional errors with `IFERROR(a - b, 0)`

Comment: I was picking up hidden cells with all sorts of non number stuff in there...

Answer (score 0):

Right I am an absolute idiot, there are hidden cells with text and I was picking them up...